# How to simulate LM2596-adj in LTspice?

Tags: ltspice, simulation, spice

I want to simulate the LM2596-adj on LT-spice. I have downloaded the models from the product page of texas instruments
they don't work properly, because they are models for 3V3, 5V and 12 V output and I don't need them,
I need a 24 V output so that's the reason why I need the LM2596-adj.
as I am using LT-spice so I [downloaded](https://www.ti.com/lit/zip/snvma62) the unencrypted version of
LM2596_5P0 and make some changes in the code by making R_RFB2=(almost 0Ω/short circuit) and R_RFB1=(almost infinityΩ/open circuit) like the way
it is presented in the blockdiagram of the datasheet. but it doesn't work,
if you can help me to complete the other changes to the model to make the LM2596-adj model
or route me to where can I find the LM2596-adj model.

[image]

[image]
*Source: TI [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf)*

Comment: I got this to work by changing R2 to 0.1 Ohms and R1 to 10MOhms. Did you make any other changes to the file? Did you rename the sub circuit in the .SUBCKT and .ENDS statements? I just changed those four lines and it seems to be working.

Comment: Why not go to the LTspice groups.io site and get the LM2596-adj  model and any expert advice you need from there?

Comment: @mooshoomatt
Can you make your comment as an answer to cite it because it works for me, thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you edit the question to elaborate what "it doesn't work" means?  Do you get an error message or something?  Can you add a screenshot of the error/problem you're encountering.  This way the answer(s) can help other users in the future with a similar error.

Answer (score 3):

Just to document the suggestion in the comments and avoid confusion with the actual resistors that need to be changed (not R1 and R2), these are the modified lines:

```
.SUBCKT LM2596_ADJ_TRANS VIN FB OUT GND ON_OFF_N
R_RFB2         FB FB_INT  1m TC=0,0
R_RFB1         GND FB_INT  1E6 TC=0,0
.ENDS LM2596_ADJ_TRANS
```

Which gives the following results:

[image]

Comment: Might be worth pointing out the reasoning behind the solution.  Most SPICE-based software can't accept resistances equal to zero ohms.  LTspice was modified so it can do it with schematic entry by flagging removal of the resistor from the netlist and circuit matrix entirely, but [still can't do it with text subcircuits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1yZW.png).  Also, for general approximations of open-circuits, `1g` is usually a better choice than `1meg`.